# Attempting to access images using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

So I am following the guide [here](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/articles/geom-gallery-array.html#geom_density_pattern) which indicates the way to access photos is as follows:

```
flags <- c(
  system.file("img", "flag", "au.png", package = "ggpattern"),
  system.file("img", "flag", "dk.png", package = "ggpattern")
)
```

My goal is to now use this code for my own uses, so I saved a few images in a folder. Here is my directory:

```
"C:/Users/Thom/Docs/Misc/Testy"
```

And within the Testy folder, there is a folder called **image**, holding 3 images. But the following doesn't seem to work and idk why...

```
images <- c(
  system.file("image", "image1.png", package = "ggpattern"),
  system.file("image", "image2.png", package = "ggpattern")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`system.file` is for use when a file included in a package. Basically, it will look for the file starting its search path to where your R packages are installed (because this can vary from user to user). `system.file` will return the resolved path to the file locally

If you already know the absolute path on your local computer (i.e. "C:/Users/Thom/Docs/Misc/Testy") you can use that as just the input to a read function, e.g. `readBin("C:/Users/Thom/Docs/Misc/Testy")`

If you want to get a little fancy or are like me and can't ever remember which direction of a slash to use on which OS, you can also do something like this which will add in the OS specific path separator:

```
readBin(file.path("C:", "Users", "Thom", "Docs", "Misc", "Testy"))
```